# Добавление массива в запрос PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

У меня есть два `ArrayList<> category` и `ArrayList<> additionalScore`, они хранят данные отмеченных чекБоксов
для того что бы добавлять эти данные в sql запрос

SQL запрос должен выглядеть вот так вот:

```
SELECT category, additional_score, name_score, defference, difference_usd FROM consolid WHERE category IN (?) AND additional_score IN (?)
```

Следующий код я нашел на SO:

```
 Connection con = DatabaseHandler.getDbConnection();
            PreparedStatement prepare = con.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
            Array categoryArray = con.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", CategorySelected.toArray());
            Array additionalScoreArray = con.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", AdditionalscoreSelected.toArray());
            prepare.setArray(1, categoryArray);
            prepare.setArray(2, additionalScoreArray);
            ResultSet rs = prepare.executeQuery();
```

Но по итогу выдает вот такую ошибку:
оператор не существует: character varying = character varying[]
Оператор с данными именем и типами аргументов не найден. Возможно, вам следует добавить явные приведения типов.
Вот так создается таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE public.consolid
(
    code character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    category character varying(500) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    additional_score character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    name_score character varying(500) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    saldo_in_som numeric DEFAULT 0,
    debet numeric DEFAULT 0,
    kredit numeric DEFAULT 0,
    saldo_out_som numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((saldo_in_som + (debet - kredit))) STORED,
    defference numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((debet - kredit)) STORED,
    saldo_in_usd numeric DEFAULT 0,
    debit_usd numeric DEFAULT 0,
    credit_usd numeric DEFAULT 0,
    saldo_out_usd numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((saldo_in_usd + (debit_usd - credit_usd))) STORED,
    difference_usd numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((debit_usd - credit_usd)) STORED,
    category_usd character varying(500) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT uniq__code UNIQUE (code)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Comment: Покажите структуру БД, `prepare.setXXX()` должен соответствовать типу данных в БД, скорее всего у вас не соответствует, оттуда и ошибка

Comment: category и additionalScore в БД у меня записаны как charcter varying

Comment: Говорить можно много чего, лучше покажите DDL скрипт создания таблицы

Comment: Добавил SQL таблицы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы путаете массив строк с `character varying` (ака `varchar`). Вам надо делать вставки обходя в цикле значения `category` и `additionalScore` и потом все добавить через *batch insert*, приблизительно так:

```
PreparedStatement prepare = con.prepareStatement(slQuery);
for (int i=0; (i < category.size() && i < additionalScore.size()); i++) {
    prepare.setString(1, category.get(i));
    prepare.setArray(2, additionalScore.get(i));
    prepare.addBatch(); //добавляем в пакет
}
prepare.executeBatch(); //запускаем пакет
```

Мануал по применению пакетной обработки SQL запросов в JDBC [здесь](https://www.baeldung.com/jdbc-batch-processing)

**Update**

Как выяснилось речь идет об `select ... where in ()`, тогда я бы предложил так:

```
StringBuilder categoryArray=new StringBuilder();
//конструируем строку типа '1', '2', ...
for (int i=0; i < category.size(); i++) { 
   categoryArray.append("\'").append(category.get(i)).append("\'");
   if (i < (category.size() - 1))
       categoryArray.append(","); //запятые везде кроме последнего элемента
}
prepare.setString(1, categoryArray.toString());
```

Comment: А этот метод работает с SELECT?

Comment: Нет, не работает :) Он работает только с `insert/update`

Comment: А что можно придумать для SELECT?

Comment: см. апдейт ответа